# cPanel API2 add forwader using php error "The address to forward is not a valid email address"

Tags: php, api, email, cpanel

Here is my request:
I just sent following request to the server:

```
$this->cpanel_api->mail()->add_forwader('subdomain.mydomain.com', '"krishna@subdomain.mydomain.com"', '"fwd"', '"krishna1bhat@gmail.com"');
```

And here is the calling function:

```
public function add_forwader($domain, $email, $fwdopt, $fwdemail='', $fwdsystem='',$failmsgs='',$pipefwd=''){
        $input=array(
                    'module'        => 'Email',
                    'function'      => 'addforward',
                    'domain'        => $domain,
                    'email'         => $email,
                    'fwdopt'        => $fwdopt
               );
        !empty($fwdemail) && array_push($input, array('fwdemail' =>$fwdemail));
        !empty($fwdsystem) && array_push($input, array('fwdsystem' =>$fwdsystem));
        !empty($failmsgs) && array_push($input, array('failmsgs' =>$failmsgs));
        !empty($pipefwd) && array_push($input, array('failmsgs' =>$pipefwd));

        $query=$this->build_query($input);
        $raw=$this->query($query);
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($raw);
        $ob=json_decode($raw, false);
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($ob);
        return $ob->cpanelresult->data;
    }
```

The print_r($raw); prints error like :

```
{"cpanelresult":{"apiversion":2,"error":"The address to forward is not a valid email address.","func":"addforward","data":["The address to forward is not a valid email address."],"event":{"result":1},"module":"Email"}}
Forward success.
```

It says: "The address to forward is not a valid email address."

But the email adding to cpanel is working fine:

```
function create_email()
    {
        $domain = 'subdomain.mydomain.com';
        $email = 'krishna1';
        $password = 'test123';
        $quota = 250;
        $this->cpanel_api->mail()->add_mail($domain, $email, $password, $quota);
    }
```

This function creates new email address "krishna1@subdomain.mydomain.com" at cpanel.

Searching for the add_forwarder issue. Thanks!